# JPA Cannot access parent class from list of child class

Tags: java, jpa

I'm trying to understand jpa relationships.

I have a `@OneToMany` relationship between two classes.

```
public class Parent {
    
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<Child> children;
}

public class Child {
  
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="id")
  private Parent parent;
}
```

I'm would like to get the Parent Id from the list of Child but the Parent is null

```
List<Child> children = repository.findAll();
Parent parent = children.get(0).getParent(); //for testing, this is null
```

But when I only get one Child, the Parent is not null

```
Child child = repository.findOne();
Parent parent = child.getParent() // this is not null
```

I'm not sure why Parent is null when using `findAll()`;